# AnimationDrawable frame duration problems

Tags: android

i need to create an animation frame by frame but i have some problems
I have 30 png images that compose my animation, i load my AnimationDrawable with this code:

```
        mCurrentAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();
        mCurrentAnimation.setOneShot(true);
        int resId;
        for (int j = 1; j < 31; j++)
        {                  
            resId = getResources().getIdentifier("resName", "drawable", "com.mindcolorstest.main");
            mCurrentAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(resId), 1);
        }
```

And logically "mCurrentAnimation.start()" to start
On mdpi device the animation works fine but i have some troubles with duration of every frame, on hdpi emulator or device i have some lag and if i will reduce duration of frames (both on mdpi or hdpi device)  the animation will not go faster, like exist a minimum duration for every frame.
Some tips and tricks? I don't know what i have to do Q_Q
Thanks anyway

Comment: Why you are using a for loop here the images are loaded on its own by the time defined...

Comment: the for loop is only to load images in the object AnimationDrawable... the mCurrentAnimation.start() will start the image background switching and create the result animation

Comment: That is a wrong way I guess, on which widget you are showing the animation....

Comment: ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageAnim)).setBackgroundDrawable(mCurrentAnimation);

Comment: I hope that you have your xml for animation file inside the res/anim folder.

Answer (score 0):

i agree on this, i do more or less the same with a xml animation-list even on the S4 i get a much longer animation time per frame then i have set. (i have set the duration to 3ms per frame). 
i messured about **`16,16ms`** per frame as minimum average over 30 cycles and 85frames.
this may or may not respond to the line `scheduleSelf(mAnimationRunnable, now + 1000/60);` in `animate()` in `DrawableContainer`. just a guess because `1000/60 = 16,66` what should become `16` as int/long cast..
but it could also come from some other limitation in code or hardware speed.
i have not checked if the code in this line gets called and is causing this because i can't somehow break there.
however i think no display is that fast in reality so it looks clever..